# Informatica PIM-Server installation

Tags: informatica

I am getting an error, when trying to install `Informatica PIM 7.1.03`(Product Information Management) core server on Windows Server 2012 R2, as below

```
Could not initialize persistence layer

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No PersistenceMetamodel available for platform datasource: XXX
```

at `com.heiler.ppm.persistence.db.internal.DataSourceRegistryImpl.getMetamodel(DataSourceRegistryImpl.java:241)`

Anyone who've already done the installation of Informatica PIM-server, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the persistence configuration files. Please find below info on that, might be one of them is missing:

All persistence unit configuration files are located in the configuration area's sub-directory called: database
 Configuration files do have a naming schema like this: [HPM:dataSourceIdentifier].properties.template.[HPM:dbmsIdentifier] (e.g. main.properties.template.MSSQL2005).

Also please check your DataSourceRegistry.